# Html bootstrap multilevel menu items are mixed with other items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to get some help with a site that i am creating but sadly I am not really good at this.That part of site consists of 2 columns and the multilevel menu/list is in the first column.When you click on the items of that menu it doesnt overlay the text that is inside the 2nd column.I would like you to tell me how can I make my menu be placed above these so it doesnt get mixed and become like this.This is how it looks. [image]

This is my CSS.

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to create a JSFiddle or CodePen, and/or post the relevant HTML code. It's difficult to see what might be happening without that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to add a higher z-index to your submenu.
The $ icon seems to have a high z-index, making it be on top of your submenu.

try adding something like

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000; /* A high number */
}
```

If that doesn't work, we'll need to see a proper example in JSFiddle or a link to the actual code

P.s: I'd reply in greek, but this is an international site. If you need help send me a message and we can talk in greek...